# CSS only rounded corners in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Is it possible to get rounded corners in IE8 using only CSS? If so, how?

Comment: HTML/CSS questions are a better fit on [Doctype](http://doctype.com)

Answer (score 3):

I know of one simple solution to use; the JavaScript JQuery plugin JQuery Corners.

All you have to do is link JQuery and the plugin using an external script reference, then add this code:

```
$("[SELECTOR]").corner();
```

[JQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

[JQuery How-To](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) (In case you don't know)

[JQuery Corners demo](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible using only CSS.

Here's [an article by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about the very topic where they offer links to other solutions.

From the article:

> While the W3C has specified the border-radius properties in its latest CSS3 working draft, Microsoft has not implemented the border-radius properties in Internet Explorer 8.
>
> Microsoft is committed to providing a browser that accurately supports Web standards. In Internet Explorer 8, we shipped several features from HTML5 and CSS3. Our primary goal was implementing CSS 2.1 (a specification that has reached final candidate stage) completely and correctly before moving on to specifications that are still in development and may change.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as well, IE9 doesn't support half of the features of CSS3.

There is an alternatively something called CSS3 PIE, but I have tried many times to get this to work but haven't been successful. This isn't to say it doesn't work, because it does, but I don't know how to get it to work.

Answer (score -3):

I'm pretty sure the CSS property:

```
-moz-border-radius:10px;
```

works in IE8, else have a look at this post: http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser

Comment: That CSS property doesn't, as it's only recognised by Firefox. Hence the -moz tag.